# Div doesn't fit inside outer div

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have three `div`s, the first (content) has another two `div`s inside.

In Chrome, the two last `div`s fit inside the first div. In MS Edge the last `div` does not fit inside the first `div`, and start after the finish of the first on the screen.

How do I force it to fit the last two `div`s inside the first `div`?

Eg. `B` and `C` must be located inside `A`:

```css
.content {
  background: #f0f0ed;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: white;
}

.B{
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 1;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="B"></div>
  <div class="col-12"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is content?...

Comment: Can you please generate a code snippet ? Will help us address your problem better.

Comment: @Alex content is the outer div

Comment: Where's the CSS for `B` and `C`? Based on your sample, B and C are inside the `content` div.

Comment: You have to give us something,we just have 3 empty divs with no width and hight nor content

Comment: just edit and add the missing style

Comment: The elements must have a `border` or `background-color` in the CSS. The `background-color` can't be white, or else we can't see it. Also, make the background color different colors so that they're easy to see. The `<div>` elements need to have a set width and height to show. Someone might flag your post if you do.

Comment: @ÂngeloRigo We don't know the styles you used, so YOU have to edit it... Copy and Paste your code from the source to here

Comment: [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMYib.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMYib.png) Please explain better your question, the `<div>` is working in the same way on my MS edge and Chrome, try change your display settings to inline instead of block, divs display block by default. And this css: background: #f0f0ed; background-color: white;
makes no sense, you're setting background color to

Comment: Shouldn't this be tagged bootstrap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you want do with the divs and what the content inside of the innee divs will be you could make the outer dive display: flex and give the inner divs flex basis values

Edit: (sorry was on my phone just got back to desk from lunch)

so you could try

```
.content {
  display: flex;
}
.B {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
}
.col-12{
  flex: 0 0 50%;
}
```

by default settings `display: flex` will line things horizontally. if you want them to be vertical you add `flex-direction: column`

```
.content {
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

any other styling is based on what you want and how you write your css in the cascade and the content of your elements

Comment: This really doesn't answer the question. You should post code that provides an example.

Comment: sorry was on my phone at lunch when I wrote the first answer